# Pairwise addition of 64-bit values in an __m512i?

Tags: avx512

I plan to use _mm512_popcnt_epi64() to get an __m512i vector containing eight 64-bit values.  I need to add those values in a pairwise fashion to get any of the following:

- an __m512i vector containing four 128-bit values
- an __m256i vector containing four 64-bit values
- an __m128i vector containing four 32-bit values

Is there a good way to do this on Zen4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__m128i _mm512_cvtepi64_epi16( __m512i a);`  (`vpmovqw`) will narrow 64-bit elements to 16-bit.  From there you can horizontally add pairs with `_mm_madd_epi16(v, _mm_set1_epi16(0x0001))` (`pmaddwd`), or with shift / add / AND, or shift / zero-masked add.

Narrowing to less than 512-bit as a first step is good for Zen4, since most 512-bit operations take extra cycles in the execution units (worse throughput and latency).

If you actually wanted a `__m512i` you'd just shuffle within lanes for a zero-masked `vpaddq`, or a `__m256i` could start with `vpmovqd` to only narrow in half, setting up for `_mm256_srli_epi64(v, 32)` and `_mm256_maskz_add_epi32(0x55, shifted, v)`

Mask register setup apparently sucks on Zen 4, with `kmovb k, r32` costing 2 uops alone (https://uops.info), so if this isn't in a loop you might want to just use a vector constant for `vpand`.  Or shift left then right, like `srli( add(v, slli(v, 32)), 32)`.  But once you have a mask in a mask register, using it is fine: `vpaddd` with zero-masking is 4/clock throughput on XMM/YMM registers, with 1 cycle latency for zero-masking.  (Or 2 cycles for one of the inputs in merge-masking).